# Random matrix theory: accounting for mean

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, random-matrices, matrix-inverse

Assume a random matrix, denoted as $X$, which is an $n$ by $T$ matrix, $T\geq n$. While I understand the typical scenario where the random variables $X_{ij}$ are sampled from a $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{i,j})$, In this case, the matrix $G= XX^{T}$ follows Wishart distribution and its general inverse $G^{-1}$ follows inverse non-singular Wishart  distribution with entries following zero mean and variance
$$
G_{ij} \sim \frac{1}{\sigma_{i,j}*T(T-n-1))}
$$ from the paper [1] below.
I am curious about a case where the entries of $X$, $X_{ij}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{i,j},\sigma_{i,j})$. What would be the distribution of the general inverse $G^{-1}$ for such non-zero-centered data matrix?

**Reference**

[1] R. DennisCook and Liliana Forzani, "[On the mean and variance of the generalized inverse of a singular Wishart matrix](https://doi.org/10.1214/11-EJS602)" (English)
Electronic Journal of Statistics 5, 146-158 (2011),  [MR2786485](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2786485), [Zbl 1274.62350](https://zbmath.org/1274.62350).

Comment: Sorry, please find the paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254211710_On_the_mean_and_variance_of_the_generalized_inverse_of_a_singular_Wishart_matrix)